# IE7 header bug navigation out by 3px

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

My website header displays fine in most browsers but when testing in IE7.

In IE7 you can see that the line that the dark blue #nav div is poking out when it should run in line with the light blue header. Is there a reason for this?

To view in IE7 go to IE9 > F12 compatibility mode

My header is 109px overall:

```
#header {
  height: 109px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

A 66px height image for the logo above starts and then a 43px height div #nav. Why is it poking out when 43 + 66 = 109px?

```
#nav {
  background-color: #0071A7;
  height: 43px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: for ur IMG class, try adding display:block; ?

Comment: The image should be a CSS background-image, not an `<img>` element....

Comment: @Shadow_boi That is the solution. Put it in your answer (*instead* of the current answer).

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

You can also put the image as CSS background-image in #header, not an  element....

---

a quick fix would be, add top: -3px to target IE7. not a best practice tho.

```
#nav{
    position: relative;
    *top: -3px;
}
```